# How to get User from database for login with Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to make login form with data from my own database. I made Entity User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Auth_data")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long id;
    @Column(name= "username")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String username;
    @Column(name="password")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name="role")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Role role;
    @Column(name = "client_ID")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long clientID;
    @Column(name = "instructor_ID")
    @Getter @Setter
    private Long instructorID;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, Role role, Long clientID, Long instructorID) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
        this.clientID = clientID;
        this.instructorID = instructorID;
    }

}
```

Also I made UserDetailsServiceIml class which implements UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceIml implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet< >();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

My User repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

I also tried make Query like this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("Select u from User u WHERE u.username=:username")
    User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

But when I enter login and password into login form I get error, because User is Null after searching in database. How can I fix it?

UPD: SOLVED!
I don't know why and how. I found that hibernate created new table "auth_data", but not used my table "Auth_data". So, I renamed "Auth_data" to "auth_data" and now it's work! I also changed @Getter @Setter on @Data,changed in User repository on " User findByUsername(String username);" and changed type of field role from enum to String.

Comment: you could even try to use this simplified version `Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);` and also remove all `@Getter @Setter` and replace it with a class annotation `@Data`. Apart from that, just a stupid question .. did you initiate your database with records in user's table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you don't seed the database with the user you are trying to login. You can use an Application Runner class to seed it on every start if the user doesn't exist in the database. Also, you can apply the `@Data` annotation from Lombok on class level to generate getters and setters for all the fields.

```java
package com.javahowtos.dataseeddemo.dataseed;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.javahowtos.dataseeddemo.model.User;
import com.javahowtos.dataseeddemo.repository.UserRepository;

@Component
public class UserDataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        loadUserData();
    }

    private void loadUserData() {
        if (userRepository.count() == 0) {
            User user1 = new User("John", "Doe");
            User user2 = new User("John", "Cook");
            userRepository.save(user1);
            userRepository.save(user2);
        }
        System.out.println(userRepository.count());
    }
}
```

Source: https://javahowtos.com/guides/107-spring/376-how-to-seed-the-database-in-spring-boot-project.html

Answer (score 1):

- You have to be sure that you have a user with the appropriate username in the database (case sensitive), if you do not have a user you can insert some test users (with the migration tool, with custom component, or manually)
- You probably need to add a unique index for username
- If you extend JpaRepository and add method findByUsername spring will generate implementation and you do not need @Query, if you have multiple items you can use findFirstByUsername